# How do I add/calculate a 'Balance' row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a transaction download from my bank, e.g.

```
Date, Amount
```

Unfortunately, the CSV download does not contain a starting balance, so I've added the initial value at the top of the DataFrame. So now the data looks like:

```
Date, Amount, Balance
2018-01-01, 0, 10
2018-01-01, 10, 20
2018-01-02, 20, 40
2018-01-02, -10, 30
2018-01-03, 20, 50
2018-01-31, 0, 50
```

Balance is computed, by adding previous balance amount to current amount.

This is what I could muster, and it smells bad:

```
df = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/Chequing.CSV", parse_dates=[0], na_values="n/a")

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Balance'] = 0

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date': ['2018-01-01'], 'Transaction': 
['CREDIT'], 'Name': ['Open'], 'Memo': ['Open'], 'Amount': [0], "Balance": [10.00]})
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])

df2 = pd.concat([df1, df], sort=False, ignore_index=True)

for i in range(1, len(df2)):
    prev_balance = df2['Balance'].iloc[i-1]
    amount = df2['Amount'].iloc[i]
    new_balance = round(amount + prev_balance, 2)
    df2['Balance'].iloc[i] = new_balance
    # Above generates a warning: 
    # SettingWithCopyWarning: 
    # A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

# While writing this, I was able to get it working by replacing the for loop above with:
df2['Balance'] = round((df2["Amount"] + df2["Balance"]).cumsum(), 2)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

print(df2.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m %B'))['Date', 'Amount', 'Transaction', 'Name', 'Balance'].max())
```

My question now becomes, is round-ing necessary? Can this be optimized or written in a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: Your `cumsum()` approach is suitable for this question. Since your `amount` and `balance` data have only non-decimal values, then no need for rounding

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@meW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10734525/mew) I would not have thought of [cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

Here's what I could do

```
%%time
df.Balance = np.concatenate((df.Balance[:1], (df.Balance.shift().fillna(0)+df.Amount).cumsum()[1:]))

#Wall time: 2 ms
```

*Comparing to for loop method*

```
%%time
for i in range(1,len(df.Balance)):
    df.Balance[i] = df.Balance[i-1]+df.Amount[i]
    
# Wall time: 173 ms
```

#### Month-wise maximum balance

```
df

          Date   Amount    Balance
0    2018-01-01       0         10
1    2018-01-01      10         20
2    2018-01-02      20         40
3    2018-02-02     -10         30
4    2018-03-03      20         50
5    2018-03-31      10         60


df.groupby(df.Date.dt.month).apply(lambda x: x[x.Balance == x.Balance.max()]).reset_index(drop=True)

          Date  Amount   Balance
0   2018-01-02      20        40
1   2018-02-02     -10        30
2   2018-03-31      10        60
```

I hope this helped. Comments are welcome ;)

Comment: That's great! I used the one liner I came up with in the original question while writing the question. Though I think your way seems a bit more clear.

The problem I am having now is how to group this so that the date (entire date, not just the month) when the balance amount reaches max value in a month is also displayed. I asked a similar question earlier, but at that time I had simple Amounts (no Balance calculated), [link](http://example.com). Specific groupby is: `df2.groupby(df2['Date'].dt.strftime('%m %B'))['Date', 'Name', 'Balance'].max()`, but it doesn't display the date correctly?

Comment: I was not sure what exactly you wanted but was this it https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS6kO.png

Comment: I think that's it! Thanks so much for you help. If you want to add it to the answer, I can mark it as accepted.